# virtual gateway interface

Tags: networking, iptables, ip, routing, route

I would like your opinion on my Linux router setup. Let's say I have default ISP (main routing table) and a specific one (routing table `custom`). Default ISP is on `eth0` and custom one is on `eth2`. For default one, it's DHCP and shiny auto routes, custom one looks like this:

```
# echo "4999 custom" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
# ip addr eth2 10.x.y.z netmask 255.255.255.0
# ip -4 route add 0.0.0.0/0 via 10.20.30.40 table custom
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE
```

So now, anything that gets routed to `eth2` is going via custom ISP. It works fine. What I want, is to create a virtual interface (VETH? TAP? I don't know) with specific IP such, that I could give it to my LAN clients and get them routed via this custom ISP. I would also prefer it to be visible during a traceroute.

LAN has `172.16.1.0/24` network. What I've tried:

```
# ip tuntap add name tap0 mode tap
# ip addr add 172.16.1.128 dev tap0
# ip rule add iif tap0 lookup custom
```

However, this doesn't work. If I specify this `172.16.1.128` as a default gateway for my clients, pings don't go past it. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

As for initial routing rule: LAN is at eth1, and I've used this to test custom ISP connectivity:

```
ip rule add iif eth1 lookup custom
```

I understand that I can add something like fwmark-based rule, but then it's back to iptbles doing all hard work (src nat), and that's slow and inefficient.

Comment: Using an alternate routing table without a routing rule referencing it has no effect. Where's the routing rule? Have a look there: https://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.html . So while "So now, anything that gets routed to eth2 is going via custom ISP." might not be wrong, chances are this never happens (the whole routing settings are needed to know for sure).

Comment: @A.B I've just updated the question

Comment: You added a new interface in the question: eth1. Why didn't you assign 172.16.1.128/24 to eth1 and thought you had to create an interface just to put an address on it rather than for the purpose of this interface (which is to communicate with an userspace process to simulate a network stack)? It's still not clear how you managed to use eth2 before this part.

Comment: I didn't because I plan to generalize the solution and then move it to different server where LAN can be on another interface

Comment: Try creating a sub-interface instead (such as eth2:0)

Comment: @BruceMalaudzi eth2:0 is not an interface: it's an address with a label (you should not use ifconfig on Linux, it's the only tool that uses the old API that makes it believe this). macvlan could be used (but it probably requires a lot of special configs). Actually it's about the same problem as there: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/716926/in-nftables-how-can-we-get-the-ip-address-via-which-a-packet-came-in-if-the-res ( https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139219/discussion-on-question-by-binarus-in-nftables-how-can-we-get-the-ip-address-via ).

Comment: @BruceMalaudzi (don't look at the answer, it's wrong despite the accepted mark)