# In nftables, how can we get the IP address via which a packet came in if the respective interface has multiple IP addresses assigned?

Tags: nftables

**Update 2022-09-15:**

It has turned out that what I was trying to achieve does not make much sense. Hence, actually this question should be deleted. However, there are some very enlightening comments to it; therefore I'll leave it as-is for the moment and leave the decision about its fate to the community.

**Original question:**

I am currently trying to learn `nftables` and have made some progress. Now I have the following problem (please bear with me if the question is dumb, but all references link to wiki.netfilter.org, which currently is down (my usual luck :-)):

I have an IPv4 network with some client PCs and a router / firewall PC which is running `nftables`. The router has two IP addresses, `192.168.20.253` and `192.168.20.254`. The former is solely for management of the router (e.g. an SSH daemon is listening on the router on that address), while the latter is the gateway address the clients should use.

In the router's `nftables` ruleset, I would like to be able to distinguish between packets which came in through `.253` (for such packets, I would allow only SSH when the `daddr` (destination address) actually is `.253`) and packets which came in through `.254` (for such packets, I would allow only them if the `daddr` is outside the local network).

I know how to achieve that if `.253` and `.254` are assigned to two different interfaces. But this is not the case; both router IP addresses are assigned to the same interface.

Could anybody give me a tip? I didn't find hints in `man nft`. It mentions routing expressions like `ip` or `nexthop`, but that obviously doesn't help. Do I need to create two interfaces (on the same NIC) and assign `.253` to one of them and `.254` to the other?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139219/discussion-on-question-by-binarus-in-nftables-how-can-we-get-the-ip-address-via).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The router has two IP addresses, 192.168.20.253 and 192.168.20.254
> ...both ... are assigned to the same interface

So we have something like:

```
# ip addr
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:f8:ed:0e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.20.254/24 brd 192.168.20.255 scope global enp0s8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.20.253/24 brd 192.168.20.255 scope global secondary enp0s8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

So both on the same physical ethernet port (L1) and the same MAC address (L2).

> I'd like to prevent clients to reach the internet via .253

That is, clients can configure the gateway on their computers as `192.168.20.253` or as `192.168.20.254`

> In the router's nftables ruleset, I would like to be able to distinguish between packets which **came in through** .253

Let see what the problem here.

...

> One of the reasons is that I would like to be able to change .253 to something else later without hassle (while .254 is "fixed").

Run simple DNS server and let client use DNS names instead of IPs to connect.

> But I have understood that I can't achieve this the normal way

Normal way in your scenario is to check dst IP and setup DNS. See above.

> I'll try to create a second interface which I assign .253 to; this would solve the problem.

You only need a separate interface if you want to separate users at the physical and data link layers.

Also IP addresses you use both from the same IP subnet so even with two interfaces it doesn't make any sense and also you will have routing problems when the same subnet accessed via two interfaces.

You cannot make 192.168.20.253 and 192.168.20.254 to be in a different subnets larger then /31 prefix.